# reading xls and xlsx file using PHPExcel not working

Tags: php, phpexcel, import-from-excel

when i reading xls or xlsx using PHPExcel it leads to a browser message *The connection was reset* 
but **when i read csv file it works fine**.
my code is

```
               /* checking extension*/  
                if($ext=="xls")
                {
                $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel5();
                }
                else if($ext=="csv")
                $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_CSV();

                else
                $objReader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007();
                /* ........end checking ..............  */
                $objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);

                $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($name);
```

Comment: timeout? memory issues? your guess is as good as mine.... though you have the advantage of being able to check the log files to see if they shed any more light on the issues you're having